# portable zip library for C/C++ (not an application)

Tags: c++, zip

I want to be able to zip files from my non-gui C/C++ application, on several versions of Windows, Linux/Unix, and MacOS.

The user will compile and run using this app using Eclipse + makefile or VisualStudio. I don't want the user to have to install something separately, or have my makefile install executables.

Prefer open-source. I'm already looking at "Zip 3.0"...

Comment: Presumably by 'zip' you meant zip and not just compress/archive? Most of the answers here recommend zlib but according to its web site zlib alone does not support zip archives http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [Libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/). I spent a lot of time seeking for a cross-platform and LGPL licensed library with convenient interface. This the best of all I've seen. Very easy and powerful tool. Originally designed for Unix-like systems but there's also [the Windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm).

Comment: Nice find. Thanks for sharing. Great documentation.

Comment: Can you please help me on the installation of libarchive, I'm currently using VS2013 and I'm getting this error `MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741571.`, when I *Rrebuild Solution* the generated `libarchive.sln` after following [these steps](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions#windowsvisual-studio).

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't help, I don't have any machine runnning Windows available right now. I'd suggest to ask libarchive devs to help with it.

Comment: libarchive doesn't work with RAR files (or better it is fundamentally broken) - hence not sure how much valuable it is given how many RAR files are around the net...

Answer (score 9):

I've had great results with miniz: https://code.google.com/p/miniz/

For a simple compression of strings in c++, I also really like [Timo Bingmann's solution](http://panthema.net/2007/0328-ZLibString.html).

Comment: Another vote for miniz. Nice single-file library. Got decompress of .zip archive working quickly.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend ZipLib https://bitbucket.org/wbenny/ziplib/wiki/Home

Personal reasons why I love this project:

- **built around c++11 stl streams** (ex. decompresses into stl streams!)
- lightweight (no dependencies other than zlib)
- can be used on both windows & liunx

It took me a long time to find this project - hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can't see how I open a ZIP archive which I got in a memory buffer. Or on disk in WinNT, 'koz filename would be in std::wstring and there're no APIs to take it.

Answer (score 6):

We've used [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) a couple times here.  It's a fairly standard library that has implementations in most main languages.

Comment: I don't think zlib can create a ZIP archive that includes multiple files. It's a compression library, and also includes functions to create one file (in the manner of gzip).

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html

HTH

Comment: and yet it's an application

Comment: And all of the mirrors are frozen. Seems dead.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned zlib, which is nice and fairly easy.

The [7-Zip (LZMA) SDK](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html) is more complex but also has very nice compression rates.

**Edit:** Although still in development, with the release process and history over time, I would be hesitant to recommend this now.

Comment: From the documentation it seems like it supports only archives in 7z format. Is this untrue?

Comment: @pqnet - I use 7zip.  It works with any compression format (zip, 7zip,. pkzip, tar, ... etc, etc)  I cannon recommend the API at this time as I have not used it, but the 7zip apps work great.

Answer (score 0):

ZLIB - the most portable library in the world. open source, very proven and reliable.  The gold standard.
why use anything else?

Comment: ... because it doesn't handle *zip files*? It just handles stream compression.

Comment: In the controb/minizip directory there are zip utilities.

Comment: @Cheeso I think you should have mentioned that.  I didn't realize minizip was included with zlib, besides there's a lot of other goodies in 'contrib'. So, I sort of feel you could edit your answer to be a little more helpful.

Comment: I did mention it... in my comment of three years ago!