# OpenSource C library for live zip file processing

Tags: zip

I'm looking for a C/C++ library that can open and read the contents of zipfiles (writing zipfiles isn't a strict requirement but would be nice).

I want to be able to open a file, enumerate the files and then efficient read (unencrypted) data from the files in the zipfile.

All the libraries I've found are all very WIN32 specific. I need something that can run on Mac OS X or iPhone (PPC, X86 or 64-bit).

I'm not worried about Zip64 (although again, that would be nice)

Edit: Please don't suggest zlib. Zlib is a library for compressing/decompressing zipped data. It doesn't know anything about actual zipfiles.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262899/portable-zip-library-for-c-c-not-an-application taken from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opensource+zip+library

Comment: I wouldn't disparage the Zlib library for only handling streams.  There is code in the "contrib" folder of the Zlib source distribution that you might find useful.  In particular see "contrib/minizip", which uses Zlib to handle .zip files.

Answer (score 2):

Would this do? [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html)? Or even [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

how about [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/).

Comment: Same response as above: Zlib doesn't actually process zipfiles. It just handles the compression/decompression of zipped streams.

Comment: However the zlib downlaod includes mini-zip which does

Answer (score 0):

Check out these guys: http://www.info-zip.org/

They make the unzip utility on linux, I'm pretty sure you could use their codebase for your projects.