# QuaZip removing files inside archive

Tags: c++, qt, zip, quazip

Is it possible to remove files inside zip archive with quazip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no function to do that.

As a work-around you can open the zip archive and then use RAW reading and writing to copy the files you want not to be deleted and put them in a new zip archive. Then delete the old archive.

This is not a very clean solution... Oh and it's not efficient either. For very huge archives it would take much time...

Comment: @Exa, thx, is here exists any other libraries for  zip access ?, i can for example use another library just to clear archive, and quazip for adding/changing files

Comment: This question might provide you with more ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262899/portable-zip-library-for-c-c-not-an-application

Comment: @Exa thx again, is any examples for accessing zip via lzma-sdk exists ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real documentation :( But you can have a look at 7zC.txt and 7zFormat.txt which come with the sdk download. I've never worked with that so I can't tell you how it is done. :/

Comment: @Exa i have tried lzma-sdk, than switched to xz-utils, i have need this for lzma stream compression, lzma-sdk looks unclear to me...