# Pack a folder into a single file with qt4 or c++

Tags: c++, windows, qt4, archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [portable zip library for C/C++ (not an application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262899/portable-zip-library-for-c-c-not-an-application)

Does anyone know how to pack a folder(on windows) in a single file with qt? I need to save a project as a single file. It seems that Qt does not have support for compression.

Comment: Your question is pretty close to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262899/portable-zip-library-for-c-c-not-an-application

Comment: http://quazip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you do "make dist" in command line or activate this target through Qt Creator Build menu, this will pack your project into an archive. This is done by build system, qmake in this case.

Comment: I want to pack a folder that my app it's creating. I know about quazip and zlib, but those libs are not helping me. I just want to pack a folder. I am not interested about compressing it. I wanted to use tar format, but I really don't know how to add the library to my QT project. I found this http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm but there are no include files. Only the dll files.