# How to extract xml files of an xlsx file into a folder in objective-C programatically.I use ubuntu machine.I do not want to use ZipArchive class

Tags: objective-c

When I download a spreadsheet from google drive as an xlsx document.I want to zip it(programatically using Objective-C) and create a folder containing the xml files of the xlsx file.I do not want to use zipArchive class.Is it possible with zlib/gzip.Kindly help with example code.

TIA

Comment: zlib and gzip don't understand zip files. You'll need a library that understands zip archives.

Comment: Oh so what is the way I can accomplish this?With my constraints?

Comment: Just drop down to one of [the portable zip libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262899/portable-zip-library-for-c-c-not-an-application) in C. You have implied that you're not having issues with iOS constraints, so you should be able to use these in shared libraries or static objects quite easily. And no, we are not going to write an example program for you.

Comment: This is a Q&A site for specific programming problems. There are several examples with the libraries that should help you on your way. If you have a problem after this point then asking a specific question will better be able to give you a specific answer.

Comment: I actually have used the inflate and deflate methods of zlib.Using which I can see that data is compressed and decompressed.But I was wondering if I could extract the xml files in it, into a folder using zlib.This is what I tried.I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: zlib doesn't have the handling for .zip archives natively. You *could* program it in, but you're better off with one of the alternatives I cross-referenced to in an earlier comment. They all work differently, so an example should be contained in the documentation for the library. You need to explain the why of not 'wanting to use the ZipArchive' library in the question