# Use zlib in a Window Runtime Component in Visual Studio 12

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, zlib

I created a Windows Store App c# in Visual Studio 12. There, I need to use native C++ code that uses minizip and zlib.

To use the native C++ code I created a Windows Runtime Component (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755833.aspx). It works. I compiled zlib in Visual Studio ([libzip with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507893/libzip-with-visual-studio-2010)), but I don't know how can I use

```
#include <zlib>
```

in a cpp file in my Windows Runtime Component Proyect.

I saw that I can install zlib.net NuGet with the Manager, in VS. But the same...

```
// Class1.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "Class1.h"

using namespace MyWindowsRuntimeComponent;
using namespace Platform;

#include <zlib.h> //cannot open source file zlib

Class1::Class1()
{
}

bool Class1::unzip(char* file) {
    unzFile zip = unzOpen(file); //need to call this function
    //...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Windows Store app a C# one? Have you added the reference to the project?

Comment: AFAIK zlib is a C project. Are you sure you don't want `#include <zlib.h>`? What do you mean with "use a #include"?

Comment: My Windows Store App is done with C#, but I need to call native C++ code that uses zlib (thats why I created the other proyect: Windows Runtime Component), and in this code, in a cpp file (or c file) I need to use a "#include <zlib.h>" to use zlib functions.

Comment: set path of zlib include directory in project settings an duse zlib.h

Comment: possible duplicate of [portable zip library for C/C++ (not an application)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262899/portable-zip-library-for-c-c-not-an-application)